# Rails 3 - Change Devise host when generating confirmation emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

Since my app works with subdomains, I need to get the subdomain the user is during the registration process. This can be made with `request.subdomain` or my custom method `current_subdomain`, and works on all the app.

But it never goes on Devise. My last try was override the `RegistrationsController` with no success at all.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @subdomain = current_subdomain
    puts @subdomain + " ON NEW"
    resource = build_resource({})
    respond_with_navigational(resource, @subdomain){ render_with_scope :new }
    #super
  end

  def create
    @subdomain = current_subdomain
    puts @subdomain + " ON CREATE"
    super
  end
end
```

Not that the `puts` work perfectly during the process.

The link that is generated on the email is on the default Devise view, and I configured like that:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm!', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token =>
@resource.confirmation_token, :host => @subdomain+".lvh.me:3000") %></p>
```

As usual it says my subdomain is nil. How can I make this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wiki article in the devise wiki concerning this:

[How To: Send emails from subdomains](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Send-emails-from-subdomains)

Devise uses the ActionMailer configuration, and your code doesn't affect those.